# Java Map util method to deep check for containKey?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, iteration, helper

Does anybody know a Util library which contains something like a `Util.deepContains()` method? I have to check a map and it's nested entries for a key. I surely can write my own logic but I like to use Utils to keep my code a bit cleaner and save some unit tests.

The map structure is `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` where `Object` can be another `Map` and so on.

Comment: What is the structure of your Map?

Comment: well nested maps as values mostly. but only two levels

Comment: Do you mean `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` for example?

Comment: `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>` because there might be more levels. But for sure the key is always a `String`

Comment: Then edit your question please.

Comment: Asking for off site resources such as libraries is explicitly off topic here.

Comment: You can salvage your question if you restate it in terms of what you're trying to do, what you've tried, then ask if is there a common name for this data structure. Once you have a common name, then you have a good chance of finding an answer with Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**, I am not aware of any existing function in a library. However, if there exist any, is it worth to import the *whole* library because of one use-case only? Feel free to create your own function. Consider the following example map structure:

```
{
    map2={
        map3={
            4=4, 
            5=5
        }
    }, 
    map4={
        6=6, 
        7=7
    }
}
```

Regardless how many `Map<String, Object>` are nested, the following recursive function iterates all the values until it finds the correct one. During the comparison, you have to cast from `Object` to `T` due to the correct comparison.

```
static <T> boolean deepContains(Map<?, ?> map, T item) {
    for (Entry<?, ?> entry: map.entrySet()) {
        final Object value = entry.getValue();
        boolean returned = false;
        if (value instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            returned = deepContains((Map<?, ?>) value, item);
        } else {
            returned = item.getClass().cast(value).equals(item);
        }
        if (returned) {return true;}
    }
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
boolean result = deepContains(map, "4"); // returns true
boolean result = deepContains(map, "7"); // returns true
boolean result = deepContains(map, "8"); // returns false
```